# Bash sending multiple curl request using GNU parallel

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-parallel

I have a list of URLs ( 5000+ ) and I need to send 25 URLs in parallel to a internal service. I know how to send the URLs request using a single query.

```
curl -s http://192.168.150.113:9999/app.boxx.com
```

And I tried using `GNU` `parallel`,

```
while true;do parallel -j25 curl -s http://192.168.150.101:9999/'{}' < list;done
```

Is it good to use `GNU parllel` ? It works good but i feel the response is quite slow and the response is similar to a single API request.

Instead , Can we use ampersand ( & ) at end of each urls and send the request in parallel ?

Comment: You might want to also checkout the `-P` (a.k.a `--max-procs`) option of `xargs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are using the full potential of GNU parallel to the extent to what is should be used. For it to work, you need to do define a smaller job (the least smallest unit that you can breakdown) and let it run for the the number of times you want.

Define a function to read from the URL, assuming the part `http://192.168.150.113:9999/` is a fixed string and rest of the URL comes from a file, define a function as

```
oneShot() {
    url="http://192.168.150.113:9999/"
    finalURL="$url$1"
    curl -s "$finalURL"   
}
```

and export this function to make it available across child-shells

```
export -f oneShot
```

and now do the magic to achieve parallelism, to run 25 jobs in parallel

```
parallel -j25 oneShot < list
```

Answer (score 4):

Inians answer is perfectly valid and is the preferred if you need to do something more complex. But if you are *only* going to do a single `curl` you can do:

```
parallel -j25 curl -s http://192.168.150.101:9999/{} < list
```