# Run curl loop in bash faster

Tags: bash, for-loop, curl

I've made a simple for loop to make POST requests using curl and save the output to a .txt file.

```
for ((i=200000; i<=300000; i++)); do
    curl -s -X POST -d "do=something&page=$i" "https://example.com/ajax" -o "$i.txt" > /dev/null
done
```

Currently, the script creates a new output in like every 260 ms. Is it possible to make this process even faster?

Comment: How about running several requests in parallel? Either with `xargs` or - in particular, if you have several computer which you can use, [`parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Comment: I never tried xargs before but I will take a look. Thanks!

Comment: @TheMineSlash, if you are not worried about output then may be you can run them in background so that it will not wait for it to complete? This is just a suggestion and not tested, so please do test this in non-prod if you are willing to give it a go here.

Comment: `curl` version `7.66` or higher has the flag `-Z` (or `--parallel`), although here it may be easier to use `xargs` (if yours supports `-P`).

Comment: Can you show me an example for parallel curl? My goal is to send POST request from 200000 to 300000 as data-value and store the output to a .txt file.
I tried to run the same exact script in 3 terminals just I edited the i increments from i+=1 to i+=3 and it reduced the processing time but i want to try parallel function too.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at gnu parallel.  You can use this to get parallelisation for anything, but it also works well with curl.  Look to replace for and while loops with it and test for optimal performance as more is not always better and there is diminishing marginal return as you go beyond a certain point.

Here is a reference to another article that discusses it: [Bash sending multiple curl request using GNU parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675116/bash-sending-multiple-curl-request-using-gnu-parallel)

I wanted to add a simple example to my previous post.

```
parallel -j8 curl -s '{}' < urls >/dev/null
```

-j8 means to use 8 parallel processes, but this can be left unset and it will try and use as many as possible.  'urls' is a text file with a bunch of URLs.

Change and apply as you see fit as it doesn't conform specifically to your example above.